# How can I pass an argument into a function with a handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, handler

This is my new code...

```html
<html>
<div class='header'>
    <a href='ks3-science.php' id='science'>KS3 Science</a>
</div>;

</html>

<script>
    varhandlers = {
        getHandler: function (str) {
            return this[str];
        },
        '#science': function () {
            $.get('load-topic.php', {
                topic: "Animal and Plant Cells"
            });
        },
    };

    $('#science').on('click', handlers.getHandler('#science'));
</script>
```

My old code was this...

```html
<html>
<div class='header'>
    <a href='ks3-science.php' id='science'>KS3 Science</a>
</div>;

</html>

<script>
    $('#science').on('click', function () {
        $.get('load-topic.php', {
            topic: "Animal and Plant Cells"
        });
    );
</script>
```

I'm just not sure how a handler works so I don't know how to pass an argument to the function with a handler.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach you argument to specific html with `data` attribute, and retrieve the data when an element is clicked in the click handler.

```js
let display = $('#display');

$('.demo').click(function(){

  let data = $(this).data('name');

  display.html(data);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="display"> Click the follwing </div>

<ul>
  <li class="demo" data-name="data1"> data 1 </li>
  <li class="demo" data-name="data2"> data 2 </li>
</ul>
```

In order to use your handler you need to wrap your handler function inside a callback as follow.

```
$('#science').on('click', function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id'); // assume the argument you want to pass is id
     handlers.getHandler(id);
});
```

Comment: how is this using my handler?

Answer (score 0):

```
var handlers = {
  getHandler: function (str) {
    return this[str]('what ever argument you want');
  },
  '#science': function (argument) {
    $.get('load-topic.php', {topic: "Animal and Plant Cells"});
  },
};

$('#science').on('click',()=>{ handlers.getHandler('#science')});
```

Comment: you're wrong because the code works. I never said it didn't work. I said, how do you pass an argument into a function inside an object (handler)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call functions passed into event handlers like you would call normal functions. So you can't, for instance, do this:

```
const myFunc = (myArg) => {
   console.log(myArg);
}

$('#science').on('click', myFunc);

myFunc("Testing...");
```

and expect it to print out `Testing...` when the event fires. Instead, you'll get something totally different. And that's because there are default parameters that these functions take - such as an `event` parameter.

If you want to call a function with a custom argument from inside of an event handler, you should do so inside of the callback function. Here's an example:

```
const myFunc = (myArg) => {
   console.log(myArg);
}

$('#science').on('click', function() {
    myFunc("Testing...");
});
```

Now, when the user clicks on the element, the `console.log` will print out `Testing...` as expected.